#  How to duplicate list members in C#?

Tags: c#, list

```
int x = 9; 
List<string> list = new List<string> {"a", "b"};
```

I want list to be: a b a b a ... until list.Count = x. How might I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work. I did not check it, let it be an exercise for you :)

```
int currentCount = list.Count;

for (int i=0; i<x; ++i)
{
     list.Add(list[i%currentCount]);  
}
```

Comment: not the downvoter but least you need to run the loop till `x - currentcount`

Comment: Bonaca: oh, I am sorry. I should have written `for (int i=0; i<x-currentCount; ++i)`, are you really such a programmer? PS. in this case you should also handle the case when `x < currentCount`.

Comment: PS. Stackoverflow is more of a guidance, at least it should be especially for people at your level. You should not expect others to write code for you. Otherwise you will never learn...

Comment: Michal, ThankYou. It works now. I hope - i will be a programmer likeYou. Thanks for the notes about x < currentCount.

Comment: No problem. And sorry for being harsh. By the way: there are nicer solutions like those from Jon Skeet. Just use `x` instead of `count` in his examples. They make use of LINQ, which you will probably learn in the future.

Comment: Personally I definitely prefer the LINQ-based approach, which separates the original list from the result. LINQ tends to favour this sort of approach over mutating existing collections.

Comment: Jon, I think every experienced developer will prefer LINQ-based approach. However, for beginners LINQ is magic, while such code can be explained. Moreover - you can rewrite it as a function that returns a new list without mutating the original one.

Answer (score 4):

You could do it with LINQ easily:

```
List<string> result = (from ignored in Enumerable.Range(0, int.MaxValue)
                       from item in list
                       select item).Take(count).ToList();
```

Or without using a query expression:

```
List<string> result = Enumerable.Range(0, int.MaxValue)
                                .SelectMany(ignored => list)
                                .Take(count)
                                .ToList();
```

The use of `Enumerable.Range` here is just to force repetition - like Ani's approach of using `Enumerable.Repeat`, which will work too of course.

Comment: Error: The name 'count' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @Bonaca: Well you need to use a bit of common sense. I used `count` as a rather more descriptive name than the `x` you used in your question. If you *really* have a variable just called `x` representing the *count* of how many items to produce, just change my code to use `x` instead of `count`.

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
var result= Enumerable.Repeat(new[] { "a", "b" }, int.MaxValue)
                      .SelectMany(strArray => strArray)
                      .Take(x)
                      .ToList();
```

Comment: i cant't do this because my list is not allways "a", "b". Next time my list is "1", "2" - or whatever.

Comment: Well then replace the array with a variable (method parameter perhaps?) and then populate as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

```
int x = 9;
List<string> list = new List<string> {};

for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
{
    list.Add("a");
    list.Add("b");    
}

// verify    
foreach (var item in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);    
}
```

Comment: I cant't do this because my list is not allways "a", "b". Next time my list is "1", "2" - or whatever.

Comment: what do u mean? can u post an example as to what output would you like?